# What is the element name of Google search button?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am now using Selenium & Ruby to take a screenshot automatically, however, I cannot find the element name from the developer tool. How can I click "search" on google?

The code below has an error which is

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='btnG']"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)

I have tried

submitElement = driver.find_element(:name, 'svg')
submitElement = driver.find_element(:class, 'FAuyhb')

But did not work.

[image: photo1]

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

driver.navigate.to "https://www.google.co.jp/imghp"

inputElement = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')

inputElement.send_keys "iPhone11"

submitElement = driver.find_element(:name, 'btnG')


submitElement.click

driver.save_screenshot('tabetai.png')

driver.quit
```

Comment: Actually, there are 2 elements with name q on Google Page. First one is for mobile users. Use find_elements to get list of elements and get 2nd element (index 1)

Comment: How can I get the second one more concrete?

Comment: just a note: there is a convenience method in Selenium for submitting forms... element.submit()  This can be used on any element in the form to submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath:

> //button[@type='submit']

Use this line

```
driver.find_element(:xpath => "//button[@type='submit']")
```

For the search icon in image search.

Comment: Actually your code and screen shot are different pages.

Comment: submitElement = driver.find_element(:button, 'submit')←you mean this?

Comment: driver.find_element(:xpath => "//button[@type='submit']").click & delete submitElement.click WORKED